# Where can you download the IPA chart with audio?

Tags: ipa, resource-request, online-resources

Where can you download or obtain (preferably freely) such a chart like http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/ **with each phone pronounced**, for offline use?

Comment: http://www.antimoon.com/how/pronunc-soundsipa.htm

Answer (score 1):

The UCLA phonetics lab has a web page that hosts the materials on the CDs of Peter Ladefoged's books. [Here](http://www.phonetics.ucla.edu/course/chapter1/chapter1.html) is a link to his performances of the IPA chart.

[EDIT]

This is too long to feed into a comment. NTNU has a web page with [IPA recordings](http://www.ling.hf.ntnu.no/ipa/full/), which does not work. They have a Norwegian version [here](http://www.ling.hf.ntnu.no/ipa/no/), which does work. You can also download the relevant files where it says "Last ned norske_spraklyder.zip" (i.e. click [this](http://www.ling.hf.ntnu.no/ipa/no/norske_spraklyder.zip)) which will give you a zip file with the folder "norske_spraklyder". If you unzip the file and go to that directory, then navigate to the folder "no", you can click "index.html". Under "Innhold" you have the option of "Konsonanter", "Vokaler", and let's skip the other two. It's quite possible that this still won't play (browser configuration stuff), but in theory you now have the material on your computer. The sound files are in the subdirectory "snd". So if you want to hear "p", you can hover over "p" and it will tell you that the sound is "IPA101", so you can click IPA101.mp3 and hear [aˈpʰa]. You can also click IPA101_i.mp3 and hear a female speaker's production.

Comment: I prefer [this audio IPA chart](http://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAlab.htm) as, unlike the UCLA one linked in the answer, it doesn't load a new page with just the audio of the particular segment I've chosen (course that might be to do with browsers).

Comment: It does have to do (partially) with browser settings, but one can spend forever monkeying with browsers, when it comes to playing sound files. This is a good resource, because it gives (I believe) performances by John Esling, so there are now two expert IPA performances out there on the web.

Comment: @user6726 Thanks. To confirm, can all audio (for all phones) be downloaded? I apologise if I missed it.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Can all audio in your link be downloaded?

Comment: @LePressentiment, something changed so that a general browser "save page" does not work as it used to.  Dunno if there is a solution short of changing your browser action for clicking the file type to "save file" and manually clicking the two sides of each letter.

Comment: @LePressentiment yes. While the sounds can't be downloaded from the page with the chart, they can be downloaded from [here](http://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAsounds/), you just have to know the name of the sound you want to download. Thinking again about your question, this may not be quite what you want as you still don't have 'the IPA chart with audio' for offline playing (if that's what you're after).

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut You are correct that I do desire `'the IPA chart with audio' for offline playing (if that's what you're after)`; I was hoping to avoid downloading each phone manually and anew.

Comment: @LePressentiment Ok sorry, I don't think there's such a resource freely available. You may however be able to download the appropriate folders and pages from [here](http://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/) and set them up to work off-line?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few good links from wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_pulmonic_consonant_chart_with_audio

https://pronuncian.com/sounds/