# where can i download ipa chart with audio offline?

Tags: phonetics, ipa

i have seen (this)[[Where can you download the IPA chart with audio?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14417/where-can-you-download-the-ipa-chart-with-audio)) and can not find any solution to my problem.

i want the ipa chart with audio offline.
where can i download it from?

Comment: Nothing to do with linguistics

Comment: @Wilson This is the community most able to answer the question, I think

Comment: You link to this same question and its answer. That pretty much makes this a duplicate.

Comment: @user6726 there are two solution available one does not work i.e the link provided no more exists( server not found) and another is norwagian version i dont know how to translate to english.

Comment: The UCLA link works. You're not going to get a solution to the problem by just asking the same question again.